# Extracting values from XML column in Oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xmltable

I have some data in an Oracle table which is stored in an XML-format string (column `response` in table `WS_LOG`).

I would like to extract data from each different node below `<MedicalProcedureOutput>`, but I'm having some difficulties in getting to each of the nodes. Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?

Here's what I'm trying (here trying to retrieve the value for the `icpcID` tag):

```
 SELECT a.id,
  t1.icpcID FROM
  GH.WS_LOG a, 
  xmltable(
  xmlnamespaces(
'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as "soap",
'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as "xsd",
'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as "xsi"),
'/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/createBillingSubmissionForAFEBSGResponse/createBillingSubmissionForAFEBSGResult/proceduresList/MedicalProcedureOutput' passing xmltype(a.response) columns
icpcID varchar2(50) path 'ipcdId') t1
```

And here's some example data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <createBillingSubmissionForAFEBSGResponse xmlns="urn:bcpcorp.net/ws/bsgFacets/FacetsBillingService">
         <createBillingSubmissionForAFEBSGResult>
            <status>0</status>
            <outputMessage />
            <statusElement />
            <claimID>18E002021300</claimID>
            <claimStatus>01</claimStatus>
            <claimStatusReason>AGFP</claimStatusReason>
            <totalChargeValue>35.0000</totalChargeValue>
            <totalPayableValue>0.0000</totalPayableValue>
            <paitentPaidvalue>17.5</paitentPaidvalue>
            <totalDebitAmount>0</totalDebitAmount>
            <proceduresList>
               <MedicalProcedureOutput>
                  <ipcdId>011801</ipcdId>
                  <otherdisallowedAmountResponsibility>N</otherdisallowedAmountResponsibility>
               </MedicalProcedureOutput>
            </proceduresList>
         </createBillingSubmissionForAFEBSGResult>
      </createBillingSubmissionForAFEBSGResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I would expect to be getting the value '011801'. Please note that multiple `<MedicalProcedureOutput>` nodes may occur, and they would be organized as follows:

```
               <MedicalProcedureOutput>
                  <ipcdId>725013</ipcdId>     
          <otherdisallowedAmountResponsibility>N</otherdisallowedAmountResponsibility>
               </MedicalProcedureOutput>

               <MedicalProcedureOutput>
                  <ipcdId>725105</ipcdId>   
            <otherdisallowedAmountResponsibility>N</otherdisallowedAmountResponsibility>
               </MedicalProcedureOutput>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare a default namespace for everything from within the body, since `createBillingSubmissionForAFEBSGResponse` has its own `xmlns` unnamed (therefore default) declaration which applies from that node onwards; so:

```
SELECT a.id,
  t1.icpcID FROM
  GH.WS_LOG a,
  xmltable(
  xmlnamespaces(
default 'urn:bcpcorp.net/ws/bsgFacets/FacetsBillingService',
'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as "soap",
'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as "xsd",
'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as "xsi"
),
'/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/createBillingSubmissionForAFEBSGResponse/createBillingSubmissionForAFEBSGResult/proceduresList/MedicalProcedureOutput' passing xmltype(a.response) columns
icpcID varchar2(50) path 'ipcdId') t1
/

        ID ICPCID
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 011801
```

or with multiple nodes as you showed later int he question this will return:

```
        ID ICPCID
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         2 725013
         2 725105
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=054745e186553a092f102c033bbfb57c)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look into to solve it with the `EXTRACTVALUE` function, [here You can find](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions052.htm) some information about it.

Comment: This should have been a comment as it does not try to answer the question..

Comment: I tried the following :  EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(A.response), '//Envelope/Body/createBillingSubmissionForAFEBSGResponse/createBillingSubmissionForAFEBSGResult/proceduresList/MedicalProcedureOutput/ipcdId'), but it still returns NULL...

Comment: `extractvalue` is also deprecated from 11g, so better to use XMLQuery or XMLTable anyway.